# How to call Realm function via HTTP?

Tags: mongodb, realm

I need to call realm function via HTTP not sdk. Looks like it is possible, but I can not figure it out.

Reason behind it is simple, I do not need anything sdk provides us, I just want to get the data from db. Also I have a problem with sdk cos it's trying to create a folder related to sync (I do not need sync at all! This is big question why Mongo dev team did it this way) in google cloud function where I get the error about read/write permissions.

Would be grateful for any help

Comment: All of the SDK's can access MongoDB Atlas directly - you do not have to use any other features of the SDK (Sync etc). So you can really do this from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer is pretty obvious we just need to use web sdk not node sdk cos web does not have anything related to sync